# Vectorizing pairwise permutation

Tags: python, numpy

Without loss of generality, let's say I have a 1-d array `X` that I want to use to construct a 3-d array `Y` that contains all pairwise permutations of `X[i], X[j]`

In other words:

```
Y = np.zeros((X.shape, X.shape,X.shape))
for i in range(len(X)):
  for j in range(len(X)):
    Y[i,j,:] = X
    Y[i,j,[i, j]] = Y[i,j,[j, i]]
```

Can this be vectorized?  Or can there be some fancy indexing that we can construct from a 2-d array of indexes to be permuted?

Comment: If your `X` is of size `n`, you only need `n(n-1)/2` pairwise permutations but you are saving `n*n` such permutations which include repetitions. Is that what you intend to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not need that many permutations. But if you want to get exactly the same `Y` as in your code, you can do (this is doing the same, only instead of looping, creating advanced indexing `idx` of all pairwise permutations):

```
n = X.size
idx = np.array(np.meshgrid(np.arange(n),np.arange(n))).T.reshape(-1,2)
Y = np.repeat([X],n*n,0).reshape(n,n,n)
Y[idx[:,0][:,None],idx[:,1][:,None],idx] = Y[idx[:,0][:,None],idx[:,1][:,None],idx[:,[1,0]]]
```

Comment: That's awesome!

Although I realized the solution to the problem was much simpler than what I *thought* was needed (above).